# ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account at httpProvider.request

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, contract-debugging, hardhat, dapp-debugging

I've been trying to debug this for about 8 hours now and have made no progress at all. I am new to programming and attempting to design a very basic DAO. Each time I attempt to deploy my contracts using 'npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost' it returns the following error:

```
ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
    at HttpProvider.request (/Users/angelachaseling/Desktop/_exchange/exchange/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)
    at AutomaticSenderProvider.request (/Users/angelachaseling/Desktop/_exchange/exchange/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:351:34)
    at AutomaticGasProvider.request (/Users/angelachaseling/Desktop/_exchange/exchange/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:136:34)
    at AutomaticGasPriceProvider.request (/Users/angelachaseling/Desktop/_exchange/exchange/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:213:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/Users/angelachaseling/Desktop/_exchange/exchange/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

Here are my two basic smart contracts (*they are unfinished however any tips on where I've gone wrong would be appreciated), as well as my deployment script and hardhat config

**nativeToken.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {

    string public constant name = "GovernorToken";
    string public constant symbol = "GT";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;


    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    uint256 totalSupply_ = 10 ether;


   constructor() {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner]-numTokens;
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Governance.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "./nativeToken.sol";

contract Governor {

    ERC20Basic public _token;
    address public contractAddress;

    uint public count;

    uint public contractBalance = _token.balanceOf(contractAddress);
    uint public userBalance = _token.balanceOf(msg.sender);

    mapping(uint => Proposal) proposals;

    event SubmitProposal(address proposer, address addressTo, uint startingTime, uint tokenAmount, string description);
    event SubmitVote(uint proposalID, address voter, uint votesYes, uint votesNo);
    event ProposalProcessed(uint proposalID, address addressTo, uint tokenAmount, string description);

    struct Proposal {
        address proposer;
        address addressTo;
        uint proposalID;
        uint startingTime;
        uint tokenAmount;
        uint votesYes;
        uint votesNo;
        string description;
    }

    
    constructor() {
        contractAddress = address(this);
        count = 1;
    }


    function createProposal(address _addressTo, uint _tokenAmount, string memory _description) public {
        uint proposalID = count;
        Proposal storage _proposal = proposals[proposalID];
        proposals[proposalID].proposer = msg.sender;
        _proposal.addressTo = _addressTo;
        _proposal.startingTime = block.timestamp;
        _proposal.tokenAmount = _tokenAmount;
        _proposal.votesYes = 0;
        _proposal.votesNo = 0;
        _proposal.description = _description;
        count += 1;
        emit SubmitProposal(msg.sender, _addressTo, block.timestamp, _tokenAmount, _description);
    }


    function processProposal(uint proposalID) public returns (bool proposalPassed) {
        Proposal storage _proposal = proposals[proposalID];
        if (_proposal.votesYes > _proposal.votesNo) {
            proposalPassed = true;
        } else if (_proposal.votesYes <= _proposal.votesNo) {
            proposalPassed = false;
        }
        if (proposalPassed = true) {
            contractBalance = contractBalance - _proposal.tokenAmount;
            userBalance = userBalance + _proposal.tokenAmount;
        }
        emit ProposalProcessed(proposals[proposalID].proposalID, _proposal.addressTo, _proposal.tokenAmount, _proposal.description);
    }


    function submitVote(bool vote, uint proposalID) public {
        Proposal storage _proposal = proposals[proposalID];
        if (vote = true) {
            _proposal.votesYes = _proposal.votesYes + userBalance;
        } else if (vote = false) {
            _proposal.votesNo = _proposal.votesNo + userBalance;
        }
        emit SubmitVote(proposalID, msg.sender, _proposal.votesYes, _proposal.votesNo);
    }


}
```

**deploy.js**

```
const hre = require('hardhat');

async function main() {
  const Governance = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('Governor');
  const governance = await Governance.deploy({ gasLimit: 150000 });

  await governance.deployed();

  console.log('Governance deployed to:', governance.address);

  const Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('GovernorToken');
  const token = await Token.deploy({ gasLimit: 150000 });

  await token.deployed();

  console.log('Token deployed to:', token.address);

  

}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**hardhat.config.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('.secret').toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
    },
  },
  solidity: '0.8.4',
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an issue with the line:

```
 uint public contractBalance = _token.balanceOf(contractAddress);
```

As you can see in your code, you want to assign the contract balance to `contractBalance` before the `contractAddress` has been updated. You might want to move all the initializations in the constructor. So, for this case, you would need to:

```
 constructor() {
        contractAddress = address(this);
        contractBalance = _token.balanceOf(contractAddress);
    }
```

Also, your `_token` is just a ERC20 instance. It needs a token address to actually get that balance you are looking for. I will recommend learning about interfaces. Your final constructor would be:

```
constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
            contractAddress = address(this);
            _token = ERC20Basic(_tokenAddress);
            contractBalance = _token.balanceOf(contractAddress);
        }
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please verify the answer so others could find solution to their problem :)